# how to check if two numbers have the same value in c++

Tags: c++

I am wondering how to check if two numbers have the same value? I just need to check value, not reference. I know in java I need to use .equals instead of "==" since the later one is for checking reference. For example, if I want to check if a matrix in armadillo library only have one element, is this good to do it like

```
if (HatMtx.n_elem==1) {

}
```

I am new to C++. I apologize if this question is too simple!

I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Your example is correct.  Be aware that floating point values can't be compared reliably for equality.

Comment: Just run the code, and see for yourself :0

Comment: I see, so I need to define like DELTA =0.0000000001; and then test if abs(HatMtx.n_elem-1)<DELTA for testing equality.

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa: That's not always a reliable approach. For example, `("foo" == "foo")` will often yield true, but it's not doing a string comparison.

Comment: @Crystal: `n_elem` is probably an integer, so that's not necessary. (And for floating-point, checking against a delta value isn't always the best approach; it depends on the nature of the values being tested.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, you are right, n_elem is an integer, does that mean that it is safe to use if(HatMtx.n_elem==1)?

Comment: Yes, integer comparison is safe (assuming `n_elem`'s value was set correctly).